# Slickgrid: Make newly added columns same width as others

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have a Slickgrid with multiple columns. None of them have a width value, so they all automatically have equal widths.

I initiate the grid and, depending on the situation,  will add more columns to the grid using `grid.setColumns()`.

The grid adds the columns correctly, but they are less wide than all the other previously created columns.

[image]

As you can see, the "Stream" column is smaller than the others.

How can I set the newly added column's width equal to the other's width?

Edit: My Version is Slickgrid v2.3

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to resize as it would when loading the grid without any defined width then you can call the following (which is the same as what the option "Force Fit Columns" would do but only once)

```js
grid.autosizeColumns();
```

or if you want to provide a fixed width and see it applied in the grid, then you can call

```js
let shouldReRender = true;
grid.reRenderColumns(shouldReRender);
```

Comment: I have ```forceFitColumns: true``` , ```grid.autosizeColumns()``` doesn't seem to do anything. 
for ```grid.reRenderColumns``` I get Uncaught TypeError: grid.reRenderColumns is not a function

Comment: the rerender is an internal function that was made a public function just few months ago and is only available in the @6pac/slickgrid fork, it you are using a different repo or you're not on latest then it won't work. The `forceFitColumns` is actually calling `grid.autosizeColumns()` internally so yeah it's normal that you don't see a difference, it's only useful if you have it off. You probably have some `width` or `minWidth` defined somewhere that might affect this, another thing you could do is disable then re-enable `forceFitColumns` via column picker, not sure it helps but worth a try

Comment: Yes, I'm not on the lates repo. For now I added the width column option and it's working that way but I'm not completely happy with this. When I have the time I'll get back to your suggestions, thanks!